# How to use getWritableDatabase() in onCreate function of SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, recursion

I am writing an android app. For that I need to populate an SQLite database with data from a txt file. So in the onCreate function of the database, I am creating the database and then populating it with the data. This is what the onCreate's declaration looks like:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
```

But when I use this line inside onCreate,:

```
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

I get this error at runtime in Logcat: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively(812)". 
So now I am unable to populate the database from inside onCreate, and am stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCreate() gets called the first time you call getReadableDatabase or getWriteableDatabase. What is certainly happening is that onCreate is getting called recursively because the db hasn't been created yet and your

```
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

call triggers the creation inside the creation.

If you need to prefill the db, just use the db argument of `onCreate` as a writeable database.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {        
    db.execSQL(YOUR_STATEMENT);
    .
    .
}
```

If you need to perform a lot of db operations, using

```
db.beginTransaction();
.
.
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLException e) {
} finally {
       db.endTransaction();
}
```

is generally faster.

Comment: You mean like this: Remove db=this.getWritableDatabase(); and just use db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);? Is db already in writable form?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Just use db as it was returned by getWriteableDatabase()